# How can I fix a chipped acrylic tub?

Tags: bathtub

I dropped something on my Kohler white acrylic tub while installing CBU and it took off a small chip from the corner. What is the best option for fixing this?

Here's a picture of the chip:

[image: fiberglass bathtub chip]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a 2-part white epoxy putty. You will need to clean/prep the area then knead the putty per the mfgr. instructions. Don't use the fast-setting variety, you need time to shape the repair to match the tub (shape using knife, file, planer, sandpaper, etc.) It won't be an invisible repair but it will stick, be waterproof, and be hard when cured.

Answer (score 1):

I had a chip fixed by a fiberglass boat builder a few years ago.

I’ll bet a surfboard fabricator could fix it too.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy a kit of everything you need at Amazon and major hardware chains like Home Depot and Lowes.

The cheap kits just contain some epoxy putty and the basic accessories you need to prepare the surface, apply the putty, and sand the hardened putty smooth.  The better kits also include finer sanding materials to polish the surface, and some form of top coat to match the color and leave a glossy surface similar to the tub's acrylic.

Here's a video of the process put out by a company that sells a kit in England.  I don't know anything about that company, but the video is well done and will give you a good idea about the process: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6b3ppGCnQME