# How to repair a small gouge in a fiberglass shower insert?

Tags: shower, bathtub, hole-repair, fiberglass

I have a small gauge (about penny size) towards the bottom of a fiberglass tub/shower combo insert in the house i bought.  The rest of the insert is in great condition, so really don't want to replace and am wondering about best way to repair.  The previous owner made a very pathetic attempt as you can see...  I have used rustoleum tub and tile epoxy paint before and am thinking that tinting that to match the off-white shower will work as the final step, but would like to fill the hole with something first and i'm not sure what.  thank you!

[image: gouge]

Comment: Auto body filler (like Bondo)? Looks like that might have been similar to what was used previously, but I think it would come out better with a little more skill and care put into it.

Comment: Or this? [How can I fix a chipped acrylic tub?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/139555/how-can-i-fix-a-chipped-acrylic-tub)

Comment: The big box stores sell tub and shower repair kits, such as ones by Keeney. They are available in white and off-white/light beige.

Comment: @GlenYates thank you, had not seen these before but now i know!